# Direct Line Speech Issues: There was an error sending this message to your bot

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to add the ability for using the direct line speech channel in my web app bot using this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

But currently I have issues with that.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsuMj.png): [Issues: There was an error sending this message to your bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsuMj.png)

Where I missed, please help me.

Comment: Please check the error in app service online editor, or in kudu console.share that screenshot also.

Comment: https://2.pik.vn/2021b0ef1b75-4ce4-4f65-82b5-d1bcba22447d.png
https://2.pik.vn/2021385f6f28-a11e-46ad-b3b6-d2bc932c2c73.png
there are no errors in app service editor, but the issue has been raised in direct line speech channel